# SSD write usage & AntiVirus impact on SSD life

Tags: ssd, anti-virus

I have the following SSD, a generation 1 OCZ 60 GB Vertex: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227394

I'm currently trying to extend the longevity of it.  I've been keeping tabs on it with the OCZ tool and CrystalDiskInfo, and it shows that I have about 29% life left. I bought this disk back in May 2009. I did the necessary steps to reduce as much writes to the disk as possible, disabling certain processes and services, moving the swapfile off the SSD, moving my browser profiles to an HDD, etc.

I want to get as much life out of this SSD, so I've been looking over things that could possibly cause these extra writes. One thing I've noticed is that the AV solution I was using, Microsoft Security Essentials, and the alternative I've been experimenting with, Immunet, tends to do a lot of writes to logs. They're small writes, but I don't know what sort of impact these writes are having on my SSD life.

What I want to know is if these numerous tiny data writes to these log files will adversely affect the life of my SSD in a noticeable manner?  Does the frequency of the writes matter (i.e. small writes to log files) versus the amount of data that is written?  If yes, why and if no, why not?

There was a previous question that asked something similar to mines here: [Antivirus impact on SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/218245/antivirus-impact-on-ssd)  But I felt neither of the answers were sufficient and an answer wasn't selected by the user who originally asked the question.  My question is a more specific version of that question since I'm primarily concerned about the log file writes that antivirus software in general are known to do.

Comment: meh, if log writes are a concern for you, I bet that the OS is writing way more than any AV client will be to begin with.

Comment: I'm hard pressed to imagine if there is even a deterministic answer to this. The words, **noticable** and **adversely**, don't help the question any. There are no objective standards defined in the question here. And yet you have not defined any of your own standards either. In light of undefined standards, viewers are forced to use their own standards, thus making each answer measured to the answerer's very own standards.  What a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect a OS to be entirely "read-only". Windows itself writes stuff in the infamous SXS folder, windows updates, registry writes, temporary files, and temporary files of all other applications for which you have not been able to move the temp files.

Anti-virus log files, and any type of log files in general, are likely a drop in the sea.

In my opinion, to minimize writes your next (and last) best bet is probably to move your entire User folder, or at least your User/AppData folder where most writes from applications are made (including your AV), to a separate HDD. However there's no easy way to do that. The best I could find, and one I could actually see myself attempting, is [this procedure](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7) using Junctions.

Overall, it looks easier/faster than creating a custom unnattended new windows installation, which is another way to do it properly. Also if you keep the original, renamed folder, you can probably manage to restore things to the way they were.

But if you attempt this, **make sure to backup your stuff** and read instructions thoroughly - you may end up having to reinstall windows if something fails. Ohhh.... just imagine of all the SSD writes this would cause!!

Comment: Yeah, I did a bit more research and learned that the "Life Left" reading via the SMART info is pretty much bogus, so there is little for me to worry about.  That's the next thing I was thinking of doing - moving the Users folder to somewhere else.  I need to think really hard about this one - if the HDD with the Users folder fails, it's going to take some work to get it working with a backup copy, if I recall.